# on pressed the elevated button its should point on Text feild,but i am facing a error when on pressed

Tags: android, flutter, dart, button

on pressing the elevated button the cursor must go to the Text feild
but am facing an error like this:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on M2003J15SC in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:64987/N4nL0hg-cQU=/ws
E/ion     (13885): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
I/vehicle_parkin(13885): Compiler allocated 4379KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
I/vehicle_parkin(13885): ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=1121 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
The following FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Invalid number (at character 1)

^

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      int._handleFormatError (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:129:7)
#1      int.parse (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:55:14)
#2      _HomeState.build.showTextFields.<anonymous closure>
#3      State.setState
#4      _HomeState.build.showTextFields
#5      _InkResponseState.handleTap
#6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
#7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
#8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer
#10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent
#11     PointerRouter._dispatch
#12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure>
#13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617:13)
#14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes
#15     PointerRouter.route
#16     GestureBinding.handleEvent
#17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
#18     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
#19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately
#20     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent
#21     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
#22     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
#23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:167:13)
#24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:341:7)
#25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#38721
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: possible
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(289.6, 338.4)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(229.6, 25.0)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
V/PhoneWindow(13885): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@81d85c9, this = DecorView@5cb64ce[MainActivity]
I/AssistStructure(13885): Flattened final assist data: 400 bytes, containing 1 windows, 3 views
D/InputConnectionAdaptor(13885): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on
D/MIUIInput(13885): [KeyEvent] ViewRootImpl KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1215968560, downTime=1215968560, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 }
D/MIUIInput(13885): [KeyEvent] ViewRootImpl KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x48, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1215968644, downTime=1215968560, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 }

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid number (at character 1)

^
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid number (at character 1)

^
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid number (at character 1)

^
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid number (at character 1)

^
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid number (at character 1)

^
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid number (at character 1)

^
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid number (at character 1)

^
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid number (at character 1)

^
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════
Invalid number (at character 1)

^
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

on taped on the button cursor must move to text feild
...
i tried like this,this is my source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
   final GlobalKey _parentKey = GlobalKey();
  int countItems = 0;
  late TextEditingController textController;
  String? vehicle;
  //String? vehicleNumber; //no radio button will be selected
  //String vehicle = "bike"; //if you want to set default value
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textController = TextEditingController();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     void showTextFields() {
      setState(() {
        countItems = int.parse(textController.text);
      });
    }
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("GL-Complex"),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 106, 19, 19),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(36),
          child: Column(children: [
            Text(
              "GL-Parking(Vehicles)",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Divider(),
            RadioListTile(
              title: Text("Bike"),
              value: "bike",
              groupValue: vehicle,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  vehicle = value.toString();
                });
              },
            ),
            RadioListTile(
              title: Text("Car"),
              value: "car",
              groupValue: vehicle,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  vehicle = value.toString();
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: showTextFields,
                    child: Text("Check In"), //label text
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 106, 19, 19),
                      minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed:showTextFields,
                    child: Text("Check Out"), //label text
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 106, 19, 19),
                      minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(
                          50), //elevated btton background color
                    ),
                  ),
                ])),
                const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: textController,
                decoration:
                    const InputDecoration( 
                    labelText: 'Vehicle Number'
                    ),   
              ),
            ),
           const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            (countItems > 0)
                ? Flexible(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: countItems,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return TextField(
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            cursorColor: Colors.white,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Enter the Vehicle Number " + index.toString(),
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                : const SizedBox(),
               
             Container(
               color: Colors.grey[200],
               padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
               child: Row(children: [
                Text(
                  "Print:",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 80,
                ),
               Expanded(
                  child: TextButton.icon(
                    onPressed: () {
                      
                    },
                    icon: Icon(Icons.print),
                    label: Text('Save&Print'),
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
             ]),
            )
          ]
          ),
          ),
        )
        );
  }
}
```

could you please please help me out to solve thisss...:)

please help me out to get the solution to the code there when on  pressed it musth appear on a text feild:

like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omV70.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Description of your problem is not very clear, you are trying to parse the text in a text field to integer when there is nothing in that text field so it is giving out an error.

If focusing on text field is all you want, you can use a focus-node here. I modified your code to do just that, I commented out the part where you are trying to parse the text in the field as number.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final GlobalKey _parentKey = GlobalKey();
  int countItems = 0;
  late TextEditingController textController;
  String? vehicle;

  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();

  //String? vehicleNumber; //no radio button will be selected
  //String vehicle = "bike"; //if you want to set default value
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textController = TextEditingController();
  }

  void showTextFields() {
    focusNode.requestFocus();
    // setState(() {
    //   countItems = int.parse(textController.text);
    // });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("GL-Complex"),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 106, 19, 19),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(36),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text(
                "GL-Parking(Vehicles)",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Divider(),
              RadioListTile(
                title: Text("Bike"),
                value: "bike",
                groupValue: vehicle,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    vehicle = value.toString();
                  });
                },
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                title: Text("Car"),
                value: "car",
                groupValue: vehicle,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    vehicle = value.toString();
                  });
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: showTextFields,
                      child: Text("Check In"), //label text
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 106, 19, 19),
                        minimumSize: const Size.fromHeight(50),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: showTextFields,
                      child: Text("Check Out"), //label text
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Color.fromARGB(255, 106, 19, 19),
                        minimumSize:
                            const Size.fromHeight(50), //elevated btton background color
                      ),
                    ),
                  ])),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20.0),
                child: TextField(
                  focusNode: focusNode,
                  controller: textController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Vehicle Number'),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              (countItems > 0)
                  ? Flexible(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: countItems,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return TextField(
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              cursorColor: Colors.white,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Enter the Vehicle Number " + index.toString(),
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[400]),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                    )
                  : const SizedBox(),
              Container(
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                child: Row(children: [
                  Text(
                    "Print:",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 80,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(Icons.print),
                      label: Text('Save&Print'),
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Colors.green),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              )
            ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I suggest you put an if check like :

```
  if(textController.text.trim().isEmpty)
```

before parsing it to number.

Comment: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'requestFocus' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: requestFocus()
its showing error after adding focus node

Comment: can you please suggest me how to solve this and where to eddit this if check....

Comment: @BhavyaN  "The method 'requestFocus' was called on null." this error should no appear, did you use the code I sent? Also which version of flutter are you using?

I suggested to place the if check in the "showTextFields" method.

Comment: okay thankyou.sir said to change the design...so am using toggle buttons:)